# The connection between SQL and Postman doesn't let me post a date

Tags: node.js, postman

This is the request of my server:

```
public async create(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        await pool.query(`exec CrearUser @password = '${req.body.password }', @creationdate = '${req.body.creationdate}', @activestate  = '${req.body.activestate }', @modificationdate  = '${req.body.modificationdate }'`);
        console.log(req);
        res.json({ 'Text': 'User creado' });
    }
```

And this is the post of postman:

```
{
    "Password": "password5",
    "CreationDate": "01-01-2024",
    "ActiveState": true,
    "ModificationDate": null
}
```

But when I send the post, the console tell:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' ', ..."tionDate": null
> }" is not valid JSON
> at JSON.parse ()
> at parse (E:\Final Semestre\Server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
> at E:\Final Semestre\Server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
> at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
> at invokeCallback (E:\Final Semestre\Server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:231:16)
> at done (E:\Final Semestre\Server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:220:7)
> at IncomingMessage.onEnd (E:\Final Semestre\Server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:280:7)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:518:28)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

I know that the problem is from the SQL Server but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with SQL Server? The error says `Unexpected token ' ', ..."tionDate": null }" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse ()` which implies it cannot be parsed within your code.

Comment: I'm not sure passing the password in clear text like that is a good idea either.

Comment: Yeah,  I know that the problem is the way that i send the request to sql server, but i didn´t know how to fix it. This program is just a prototype

Comment: It's **NOT** SQL server that is giving the error, it is your code

Comment: Yeah I lnow, but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: The error tells you that as well, for some reason it can't parse the JSON... the provided answer below has an explanation... but I know nothing about nodejs so can't advise further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the error is here, but from your `SyntaxError`, I can tell you that, when you call from the Postman, your server was trying to parse the

```json
{
    "Password": "password5",
    "CreationDate": "01-01-2024",
    "ActiveState": true,
    "ModificationDate": null
}
```

to the Object.
But the real problem is, your input data is an object itself, so it can't perform the `JSON.parse()` function.

Extra: If you are using Express, or similar frameworks, I think use the `body-parser` or some familiar packages maybe help in this case.